# Python logger not working with subproccess

Tags: python, logging

I am attempting to run code from one program (program1) via the usage of a subproccess.popen call. Program 2(the one being called) does not display logger statements. In the example code below program1 calls program2 with logging setup for each code.

program1.py

```
import subprocess
import logging
import sys

def configure_logging(name):
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s:%(name)s:%(message)s")
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
    return logger

logger = configure_logging(__name__) 
python_path = "Path/to/specific/pythonexe"
py_path = "Path/to/program2.py"    
cmd = "{} {}".format(python_path,py_path) 
logger.info("Cmd: {}".format(cmd)) 
cmd = cmd.split()        
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True)
```

program2.py

```
import logging
def logstuff(name):
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s:%(name)s:%(message)s")
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
    return logger

def main():
    logger.info("hi")
    print("hi2")

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    logger = logstuff(__name__)
    main()
```

Using the above setup program1 calls program2 but the logger.info statement is not printed out only the print() statement is.

I can't import program2 as it relies on a specific python version encased in an anaconda environment.

My desired output would be to have the logger.info and any subsequent logger calls printed to terminal so how would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you messed up with the logger setup. Also the subprocess.Popen with stdout PIPE and such didn't work for me. Here's what I got working locally, hope it helps.

**program1.py**

```
import logging
import subprocess

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(name)s:%(message)s')
stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

python_path = 'python'
py_path = 'program2.py'
cmd = '{} {}'.format(python_path, py_path)
logger.info('Cmd: {}'.format(cmd))
cmd = cmd.split()
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

**program2.py**

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(name)s:%(message)s')
stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(stream_handler)


def main():
    logger.info('hi program2 here')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
$ python program1.py 
2018-11-14 15:38:53,905:__main__:Cmd: python program2.py
2018-11-14 15:38:53,917:__main__:hi program2 here
```